# CRUD bulk update/insert through an ajax proxy

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, proxy

I was working on bulk update/insert through an ajax proxy. I use `store.sync()` this will hit the server for every dirty records but if I get error in any one of the record in server, how to notify the client with proper message?

```
proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: "localhost:8888/service/baseLocations",
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success',
            totalProperty : 'total'
        },
        actionMethods: {
            create: 'POST',
            read: 'GET',
            update: 'POST',
            destroy: 'DELETE'
        },
        writer : {
            type: 'json'
        },
        batchActions: false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three methods available when a `store` is updated via `sync`.  `onUpdateRecords`, `onDestroyRecords`, and `onCreateRecords`.  You can view the `success` property coming back and `rejectChanges`

*For Example*:

`onUpdateRecords: function(records, operation, success) {
    if (!success){
         this.rejectChanges();
    }
}`